# How do I create a magazine type menu - sub-menu setup using wp_nav_menu and child of twentyten?

Tags: menus, theme-twenty-ten, child-theme, children

I'm trying to create a menu and submenu with a child theme of twentyten, similar to this at the LA Times: http://www.latimes.com/ where when the site is first opened, it displays a set of childs, and then when other parents are hovered over, other childs are displayed.

As I say, I'm trying to achieve this using the custom menu function built into WP 3.0.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: This is custom javascript, the question does not really belong here.

Comment: So something like the LA Times can't be achieved with css alone. Can any dropline type of navigation be achieved using solely css and the wp_nav_menu function. Just so everyone knows, I'm very much a self-taught wordpress user and all my css, html and now php knowledge has come from mainly online resources and books. Therefore, explanations are helpful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would be interested to see how this can be done. I did notice quite a few WP themes that display a 2nd level child menu when hovering over the main menu. Hope someone could chip in.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several solutions to this, but this is what I would do:

First set a static front page. This can be done in `Settings->Reading`.
This will cause the menu item (page) selected to have the CSS class `current-menu-item` and also to display any sub-menu items you have.

Then you just CSS them to be shown in a second row.